# Missing characters Indesign. Some characters from a specific font are omitted

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, character

I have a problem with Indesign and Futura PT Font, when I write "f" + "i" like eg. "*Confianza*","*fin*","*Confidencialidad*", the characters "fi" are not display. I have attached some photos so you can see the problem and give me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Christian Paucar
[image]
[image]

Comment: your problem seems connected to the settings for ligatures

Comment: @Luciano Thanks for your help. It's correct! When I uncheck the option "Ligatures" (Paragraph Style Options -> Basic character formats -> Ligatures), the characters are shown again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up the character window.
Click on the hamburger menu on the top right (more options)
check off (or on) ligatures.
See if that solves your problem